# SQL Query for percent of buffer filled with objects

Tags: sql, buffer, query

I am trying to write a query to find the percentage of a buffer polygon (Called 250_Buffer) that is filled with or contains other polygons in another layer (Called Development) any help that you guys could give me would be awesome.

I am hoping for an answer output as a percentage of 100 but I could also get something in square meters/acres/miles and calculate the percentage myself.

Comment: What database are the features in?

Comment: I digitized the features from a town planning map and the buffers are 250ft buffers around vernal pools.

Comment: I believe he's asking what KIND of database you are using, to which I will add what GIS software are you using? I have no idea how to do straight query (if that's even possible), but I could give a workflow solution with some geoprocessing steps to arrive at the number you want.

Comment: Sorry for being so vague I am using MapInfo but I am a little confused about the database question. I don't think that I am using any database.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with MapInfo and its [file formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapInfo_TAB_format), but when you look at your development layer, the information associated with the polygon geometry (land use or zoning) and perhaps the geometry itself is stored in a database. Different database formats have different capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a SQL Statement in MapInfo either thru the SQL Select dialog or thru the MapBasic window.

If the polygons in your development table overlap, you might need to combine these to find the correct percentage, that is avoiding a common area to get calculated more than once in your percentage.

If you need to combine the development objects do it this way:
- Make a copy of your development table and open this copy
- Add the copy to your map and make the layer editable
- Now select all from the copy table (can be done by right-clicking on the layer if you are using v12)
- Use Objects > Combine to combine all the selected objects into one
- Save changed to your Copy table and pack the table afterwards.

Now you can use this query to calculate the overlapping area:

```
Select 250_Buffer.NAME, Development.NAME
   , CartesianArea(250_Buffer.OBJ, "sq m") "Area_buffer"
   , CartesianArea(Overlap(250_Buffer.OBJ, Development.OBJ), "sq m") "Area_overlap"
From 250_Buffer, Development
Where 250_Buffer.OBJ Intersects Development.OBJ
Order By 250_Buffer.NAME, Development.NAME
```

The query above calculates the area overlap between each buffer polygon and each development polygon. If you have combined the development polygons, you now have your final result.

If you didn't combine them, you can use this query instead:

```
Select 250_Buffer.NAME
   , CartesianArea(250_Buffer.OBJ, "sq m") "Area_buffer"
   , Sum(CartesianArea(Overlap(250_Buffer.OBJ, Development.OBJ), "sq m")) "Area_overlap"
From 250_Buffer, Development
Where 250_Buffer.OBJ Intersects Development.OBJ
Order By 250_Buffer.NAME, Development.NAME
Group By 250_Buffer.NAME
```

250_Buffer.NAME and Development.NAME are columns in the two tables identifying the records, can be unique names or IDs.

If you combined the Development areas, you can also use the function ProportionOverlap() to give you the proportional overlap value.

Otherwise you will have to calculate this yourself using the area of the buffer and the area of the overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact steps required in MapInfo, or if directly comparable tools even exist, but I will outline what you would do in ArcGIS and perhaps that might lead you to a process that would work - if someone who uses MapInfo doesn't give you an exact solution.

First, you would run Union on your buffer and development layer. This would give you a new layer that would cut up your inputs into areas of common overlap - with their associated combined attributes.

Next, if your data did not have an area field in the desired units, you would add and calculate that.

Now you should be able to run queries on the union layer to ask what is both buffer and development (or even the *types* of development). ArcGIS has a tool available at higher license levels called Frequency which could give you a summary of everything at once. Otherwise you could use Summary Statistics on the attribute table to get each type of development one by one, or simply select the related records and use Statistics to look at the number.

If you're simply looking for the percentage of buffer covered by development, you could get total buffer area from original layer and total area that is still just buffer and not development from your union layer, and derive the numbers from those two. Another approach for that number, again depending on the tools available, would be to subtract (geometrically) your development layer from your buffer layer to get the undeveloped buffer area.